# Add user managable titles to custom menus?

Tags: plugin-development, menus, navigation

I am looking for a way to include a user managable title in a menu. Ideally, it will take the place of the first `<li>` object in the output.

Any ideas?

---

**Edit** *Clarification*

I am looking for a way to add a header to a menu list, defined by the given name of the menu in the admin panel.

So, the code should look a little like this:

```
<ul>
  <li class="title"> Menu Name</li>
  <li><a href=#>Link</a></li>
  <li><a href=#>Link</a></li>
  <li><a href=#>Link</a></li>
  <li><a href=#>Link</a></li>
</ul>
```

---

**Edit** *Further Development*

I have a code block for extracting the name of a menu, based on it's location in a theme, but I can't quite get the HTML layout I want (i.e. add the title to the first `<li>`).

```
function mf_get_menu_name($location){
    if(!has_nav_menu($location)) return false;
    $menus = get_nav_menu_locations();
    $menu_title = wp_get_nav_menu_object($menus[$location])->name;
    return $menu_title;
}
```

Comment: care to explain a bit more?

Comment: Added clarification and details of where I am with the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking to put a title on the nav links? That is built into the Menu feature in Wordpress.

[image: Wordpress Title Menu]

But this applies to the  tag and not the `<li>` as you specified. You can, however, apply a class to the `<li>` by clicking the "Screen Options" link while in the Menu Admin page. Then, find the "CSS Class" checkbox under "Show advanced menu properties".

Finally, you could give your links the desired title and then apply the following jQuery to apply the title to the `<li>` and remove it from the `<a>`.

```
$(function() {

    $('ul li').each(function() {

        var linkTitle = $(this).find('a').attr('title'); //get the link title
        $(this).attr('title', linkTitle); //apply the title to the li

        $(this).find('a').removeAttr('title');
    });

});
```

JSFiddle example: http://jsfiddle.net/tmort/E5VzC/3/

Comment: Sorry, not really what I meant, I have explained further in the question.